# How to create an Array with content of the HTML tags from the URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I check, the web-page exists, and add the content of all the `<H3></H3>` tags into Array? For example, URL of the page is "http://anywebsitefotesting.com"

Environment: Xcode 5, Objective-C.

Comment: That link you posted has no tags...

Comment: I understood. Trying to fix.

Comment: Now the question iscorrect.

Comment: Search for "How to get content string of URL". After that, it's a simple case of writing a regex and parsing the string in waves (regex will be quite complicated, with back referencing, since you'll have to handle <OpenTag1><OpenTag2></CloseTag2><CloseTag1>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download the page source like this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourWebsiteHere.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Then follow a tutorial like [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) one from Ray Wenderlich on how to parse and "scrape" for what you need.

Comment: Thank you for this link for tutorial. It is very interesting. I found many new things from it. It works very well.